# Can I create an RDD from a generator?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing a function to create batches of pytorch tensors for use in training a model. I want to construct the tensors and pin them to memory before executing my training loop.  To do this I will need to create batches based on some parameter `batch_size`. I want the memory footprint of this operation to be as small as possible so that I have as much memory available for when I pin the tensors in memory.  I also want to use spark to scale out the operations associated with creating tensors for a batch.  To this end I want to create a RDD from my batches.

Can one parallelize a python generator?

Answer (score 2):

Yes one can! 
Here is a toy example I ran in a notebook.

```
sc = build_spark_context(params) # custom convenience function

def foo(max_value):
    for i in range(max_value):
        yield i

bar = foo(10)
print(bar)
# <generator object foo at 0x7f3bf3d1e7d0>

rdd = sc.parallelize(bar)
result_dag = rdd.map(lambda i: i*10)
result = result_dag.collect()

print(result)
# [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```